# Significance of lower semicontinuity in (non-)convex optimisation

Tags: optimization

In the context of (non-)convex optimisation, what is the reason behind requiring that the objective function be lower semicontinuous? From what I understand, 1) a function is continuous iff it is both lower and upper semicontinuous, and 2) a convex function is continuous. So what is the link between l.s.c functions and convex optimisation?

Comment: If a function on a compact space is lower semicontinuous, then [it attains its infimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem#Extension_to_semi-continuous_functions). Convexity is usually required to state that a local minimum is a global one, as well.

Comment: Thanks @Budenn, when a function is l.s.c, its epigraph is only closed, but not convex, so is the definition of convexity weakened for l.s.c functions?

Comment: No, these concepts are independent: l.s.c. is for existence of a global minimum, convexity is to guarantee that the optimization method converges to a global minimum, not just a local one.

Answer (score 0):

***A convex function is not necessarily continuous***: discontinuities  may occur on the boundary of the domain. For instance consider the function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined as
$$
f(x)=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
        1, & \text{for } x=0,\\
        x^{2}, & \text{for } 0< x\leqslant 1.
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
The function $f$ is convex on the compact $[0,1]$, but $f$ is not lower-semicontinuous and we can easily remark that $f$ does not have a minimum on $[0,1]$.

More generally, lower-semicontinuity is a sufficient condition for the existence of local or global minima on compact domains.